# Acid content of wine vs. vinegar?

Tags: stock, wine, vinegar, broth, acidity

I'm making bone broth, and the recipe says to add 2 tablespoons of vinegar or lemon juice (to 5# bones and 5 qts. water) to help draw the minerals out of the bones.  I'm wondering about using verjus or wine instead of the vinegar (or lemon juice).  In general, how does the acidity of (1) wine and (2) verjus compare with that of vinegar?

Answer (score 2):

Verjus (the non-fermented juice of unripened grapes) is going to be more acidic than wine, but I have been unable to find a number/concentration.  Probably because a lot depends on the grapes at the time of harvest.  The acidity of various vinegars also ranges, so comparing verjus to vinegar would require much more specificity of the types of products you are intending to use.  So, if you are choosing between wine and verjus, go for the latter.